# Using ansible to create Azure resource group, throws "403 client error"

Tags: azure, ansible

Right now I am using ansible playbooks to create azure resource group on Centos 7.0, and I created a credential file like this:

```
[default]
subscription_id=my_subscription_id
client_id=<the application ID>
secret=<the password>
tenant=<my aad id>
```

and it throws an error like this:

> {"changed": false, "msg": "Error checking for existence of name ansible-rg - 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/my_subscription_id/resourcegroups/ansible-rg?api-version=2017-05-10"}

I know maybe it is because my lack permission of my subscription, but I am not sure what I should do about this.

Comment: did you grant your service principal permissions? also, how did you install ansible? this doesnt look like a permissions error on azure side

Comment: Seems your service principal does not have the permission to create the resource group. Try: navigate to your subscription in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> `Add role assignment` -> add your service principal as a role(e.g. owner) in the subscription.

Comment: Thanks @JoyWang, I will try it.

Comment: @JoyWang no, this error doesnt look like that at all

Comment: @4c74356b41   Thanks for your help. I have tried what Joy said before, and seems it works well right now...I should add service principal to the subscription.

Comment: @JoyWang Calm down man... Accepted.

Comment: Ok, have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems your service principal does not have the permission to create the resource group.

Try: navigate to your subscription in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> `Add role assignment` -> add your service principal as a role(e.g. owner) in the subscription.

Answer (score 0):

For others that might have this error, make sure to also check that your current subscription is not on Pay-As-You-Go, as you will see the same error:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error checking for existence of name * - 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/*/resourcegroups/rg-cs-ansible?api-version=2017-05-10"}
```

[See screenshot sample as seen in azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug78U.png)